# CSS flex design with flex-wrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox

I have a flex `<div>` containing a few elements (I don't know the exact number beforehand).

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">1</div>
    <div class="inner">2</div>
    <div class="inner">3</div>
    <div class="inner">4</div>
    <div class="inner">5</div>
    <div class="inner">6</div>
</div>

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Let's say I expect 3 to 15 children and they do have a minimum width but can expand up to 2x to fill remaining space (here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r3xch5n9/).

With `flex-wrap: wrap;` I can make them flow in new lines when needed. Usually result is nice to see, for example in this the case with 3 and 3 elements

[image]

But with different total width the result is odd

[image]

Is there a way to make the browser split the div equally?
E.G: In the above case I expect 3 elements per line, with a white margin between them insead of 5 elements in the first line and only 1 in the second.

Comment: the max-width seems to be in the way. min-width could be the flex-basis. https://jsfiddle.net/r3xch5n9/3/  as far as i know, flex will not be able to break in evenly rows or columns children. Javascript might be required if this what you really look after. you can see here the flex-basis(or min-width) as a breaking point

Comment: @GCyrillus thank you for the hint, removing max-width is not possible (I can't let the div occupy too much width because of the kind of content). Sadly a programmatic way is probably the only viable one :(

Comment: updated the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/r3xch5n9/4/ ( flex:1 0 120px; ) about flex-shrink:0; to mimic the min-width accorfing the the flex-basis value . good luck

Comment: You can use this
https://jsfiddle.net/r3xch5n9/5/

Answer (score 2):

Add `flex-basis: 33.33%` to `inner` and also removed the `min-width` and `max-width` for the `inner` and I guess that solves your problem -see demo below:

```css
div.container {
  border: 2px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
div.inner {
  flex-basis: 33.33%;
  height: 120px;
  padding: auto;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner" style="background-color: red">
    <span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inner" style="background-color: blue">
    <span>2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inner" style="background-color: green">
    <span>3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inner" style="background-color: yellow">
    <span>4</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inner" style="background-color: grey">
    <span>5</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inner" style="background-color: orange">
    <span>6</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you need some margin between them, you can adjust for it using `calc` like below:

```css
div.container {
  border: 2px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
div.inner {
  flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 10px);
  height: 120px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner" style="background-color: red">
    <span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inner" style="background-color: blue">
    <span>2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inner" style="background-color: green">
    <span>3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inner" style="background-color: yellow">
    <span>4</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inner" style="background-color: grey">
    <span>5</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inner" style="background-color: orange">
    <span>6</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**:

Using jquery for calculating the number of flex items in a row - see demo below:

```js
var flexChildrenNo = $('.container > .inner').length;

function modifyFlexItems() {
  var $width = $(window).width();
  // max number of elements in a row
  var num = Math.floor($width/120); 
  // find the number of flex chidren in a row
  while(flexChildrenNo % num)
    num--; 
  // calculate margin:
  // here 120 is  min-width
  // here 4 is adjustment for the 2px border
  var margin = ($width - num * 120 - 4) / (2 * num);
  $('.inner').css({'margin': margin + 'px'});
}
modifyFlexItems();
$(window).resize(modifyFlexItems);
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
div.container {
  border: 2px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
div.inner {
  max-width: 250px;
  min-width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner" style="background-color: red">
    <span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inner" style="background-color: blue">
    <span>2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inner" style="background-color: green">
    <span>3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inner" style="background-color: yellow">
    <span>4</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inner" style="background-color: grey">
    <span>5</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inner" style="background-color: orange">
    <span>6</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, this does not work if you expand to full page because the property `max-width` is set. I believe he is looking for something else, not a fixed `flex-basis`.

Comment: it solves only in some cases, if you expand the container the number of elements on rows can still be 5-1, 6-2, and so on

Comment: @Ricky_Ruiz thanks for pointing about the `max-width`, fixed it... let's ask the OP for if the result is as expected now...

Comment: @kukkuz thank you for the effort, but the content has a somehow fixed size (the minimum that I can't remove) but I also don't want to grow up to 2 times the minimum. In your example width can became huge and it can't work

Comment: @Naigel so you want to keep `min-width` and `max-width` and 3 elements per row distributing the rest of the whitespace, is that right?

Comment: @kukkuz I want to keep a `min-width` and `max-width` and an even number of elements per row. If I have 6 elements it's ok to have 6, 3-3, 2-2-2, 1-1-1-1-1-1 depending on available width. With 8 elements is's ok 8, 4-4, 2-2-2-2 and so on

Comment: @Naigel why don't you use media queries for this? You would really need to specify this behaviour for the browser giving it the according breaks for your design. I feel that the logic of display: table or flex is different from your approach.

Comment: @Naigel please check the edit above and let me know if that is the behavior that is desired? Thanks!

Comment: @kukkuz I hope there were a non javascript solution, but it seems impossible. Your solution has some glitches http://imgur.com/a/P40be but I use angularJS as framework so I'll implement something more specific :)

Comment: @Naigel a non-javascript solution is not possible here as we have to detect wrapping which is not possible in CSS... and regarding the glitch - I guess that happens if there are any default margins / borders that can effect the calculations...